# Sorting sets Q of a set S such, that all members are represented biased on S (shuffling music titles of different artists within a directory)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Starting position:**

My wife has a collection of music titles stored on her walkman. The files are all stored in a single directory, with the help of a tool I wrote plus some manual assistance, in the format

```
Artist1 - Title1
Artist1 - Title2
...
Artist1 - TitleN
Artist2 - Title1
...
ArtistM - TitleZ
```

Some artists have just as few as a handful titles (one featuring just 1 title), while others sport as many as 56 titles. All in all, the growing collection encompasses a 4-digits number of `n` titles now (about 1200).

These titles are all sorted alphabetically within that single directory, so that a title can be found quite easily, mainly for the purpose of removing a now disliked title from the collection.

This said, it should be obvious, that this collection is to be played randomly, using the walkman's built-in shuffle mode.

**Problem:**

The shuffle mode of this walkman is really not worth being called this way.

It is quite common, that songs from the same artist (stored sequentially in the folder) are played consecutively, not rarely even 3 of them in a row. This behaviour certainly is not perceived as "random".

**Approach:**

My approach was to pre-shuffle these titles programmatically, to be played sequentially. The strategy was to ensure, that an artist does not play 2 of her songs in a row.

For this I let my program evaluate for each artist the number of titles present, to determine the artist with the most titles, and found `m=56`. From that number I programmatically find the next prime `p=59`.

Now the idea was to iterate through the original alphabetically sorted list in a step width of `n mod p`, so that eventually all titles get copied in a way that they don't expose two consecutive titles of the same artist.

This works as expected.

However, after about `n/p` (currently about 30) titles, the artists repeat (with different titles, but still giving the impression "just heard her"), while many other artists featuring less than `m` titles are quite never played.

**Question:**

Is there a mathematical approach to improve my psychologically quite trivial approach to play as many titles from different artists as possible before playing an arbitrary other one of her titles (even at the expense of playing underrepresented artists more often), other than just trivially keeping track of every artist's already copied title and duplicating titles in the play list?

Comment: `The shuffle mode of this walkman is really not worth being called this way. It is quite common, that songs from the same artist (stored sequentially in the folder) are played consecutively, not rarely even 3 of them in a row. This behaviour certainly is not perceived as "random".` Our intuition about what is random and what is not is really bad. Humans are much more likely to avoid repetitions when "randomly" choosing between 0,1 to a real random generator (or a monkey, monkeys are also pretty good at randomization).

Comment: If you want to really know if it's random or not - I suggest doing Pearson test, or something similar to check the likelyhood of it.

Comment: Also, if you get uniformly random permutation, try [fisher yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Though it doesn't seem like you want uniformly random here - but more biasing towards different artists.